# Function behavior of $e^x$ and $x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

so I'm doing a math problem requiring me to find the area between two curves, $e^x$ and $x^2$. It gave intervals ($x=-1$ and $x = 1$) but I wanted to find their intersection points so I can better envision/sketch the area I'm trying to obtain. However, I find that (at least on math computational websites) that I have to graph both functions to actually find where exactly they intersect. I graphed the function on geogebra to see what it looked like and it only has $1$ intersection point. For some reason, I was envisioning that it would have at least $2$ intersection points but in this case, $e^x$ travels faster than $x^2$. Now I'm thinking that my understanding of $e^x$'s behavior is not clear. Is there any way to deduce that the functions only cross once? I always find intersection points via just equating the functions together and solving for $x$, but it seems that in this case it cannot be done.

Comment: If their difference is strictly increasing (positive derivative), it can’t be $0$ more than once

Comment: Maybe it is wise, if you shorten your question to the core question. It turns out that the question has nothing to do with evaluating integrals, as the first part implies. This would make it easier to give a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

The analytic solution for the crossover point is:

$$x = -2 W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$

where $W$ is the Lambert's W function.

This confirms there is only a single real solution.

[image]

Comment: Polylogarithm ? Lambert would be better I presume.

Answer (score 0):

As David G. Stork answered, there is analytical solution for the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^x-x^2$$ but it involves special function (Lambert in this case).

By inspection or graphing, you noticed that the solution is between $-1$ and $0$. To find the zero, the simplest could be Newton method; starting for example at the midpoint, that is to say using $x_0=-\frac 12$, the calculations would converge very fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.500000 \\
 1 & -0.721926 \\
 2 & -0.703601 \\
 3 & -0.703467
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find the intersection point, albeit approximately. Let $f(x) = e^2 -x^2$ with the root $r=-1+a$ and expand,

$$f(r)=0\approx f(-1)+f'(-1)a+\frac 12 f''(-1) a^2$$

Evaluate,

$$f(-1)=\frac 1e-1, \>\>\> f'(-1)=\frac 1e + 2,\>\>\>f''(-1)=\frac 1e -2$$

and we have,

$$0=1-e+(1+2e)a+\frac 12 (1-2e)a^2$$

Solve for the root,

$$r =\frac{\sqrt{10e-1}-2}{1-2e}=-0.703$$